# How to create two object with the same properties - Cloning not working

Tags: c#, wpf, object, cloning

I have to create two datagrid with the same properties:

```
var dtg = new DataGrid
{
    Margin = new Thickness(10),
    EnableColumnVirtualization = false,
    EnableRowVirtualization = false,
    Background = Brushes.Transparent,
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(m_ExeCfg.GetForeground()),
};
```

and then dtg2 with the same properties...
but Datagrid dtg = dtg2 = {...} is not allowed

therefore I have used this cloning:

```
string dtgXaml = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(dtg);
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(gridXaml);
System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
DataGrid dtg2 = (DataGrid)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

so how can I create two objects with exactly the same properties?

Comment: A deep clone can be achieved using a serializer as you showed above. Doesn´t it work? If so what error do you get? Any unexpected results? Please be more specific on what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck.

Comment: Ok no errors. Just doesn't clone and the graphic  effect is blatant

Comment: You'd better use XAML styles to apply common styles to different DataGrids (or any other controls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are sererializing to **dtgXaml**, but that is never used.
Instead you use some **gridXaml** variable.

```
 string dtgXaml = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(dtg);
 StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(gridXaml);
```